# Como instalar a biblioteca react-navegation pelo prompt?

Tags: react-native, biblioteca

Estou estudando React Native e já tenho o Visual Studio Code instalado, na vídeo aula ensinaram o comando

```
npx react-navigation
```

porém quando uso o comando o `prompt` me da a mensagem de erro

> `npm ERR! 404  'react-navegation@2.18.3' is not in the npm registry`

Comment: você está usando yarn ou npm para gerenciar seus pacotes, que eu saiba não utilizamos npx, bom pelo menos nos meus estudos de `javascript` e `react` nunca utilize

Comment: Meu projeto foi criado pelo comando NPX, aplicação está rodando no emulador, no vídeo foi dito que poderia ser usado o NPX ou NPM, acredito que seja um erro de digitação do comando, mas não entendo muito bem a diferença entre esses dois gerenciadores.

Comment: npx na hora de criar o aplicativo (que pega a ultima versão) é uma coisa, mas, gerenciar os pacotes ou é yarn ou é npm, então instale pelo npm ...

Comment: Tem alguma coisa estranha no código que você mandou.
O trecho de código está: react-navigation porém a mensagem de erro está como react-navegation. Notou a diferença?

Comment: No seu código deve estar react-nav**e**gation quando o correto é react-nav**i**gation.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic o gerenciador é npm. Augusto o 'E' no lugar do 'i' foi erro meu na hora de digitar aqui na pergunta, mas no comando digitei certo, mas ainda não consegui. estou usando o comando >npm install react-navigation< e não funcionou para instalar o react navigation.

Comment: O erro deve estar no programa quando importa a lib.

Answer (score 0):

Depende de qual sistema operacional vc estiver utilizando.

No windows via npm:
Passo 1:
npm install @react-navigation/native
Passo 2:
npm install react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view

Se estiver utilizando o EXPO instale instale o esse passo 2

Passo 2:
expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view